# How to migrate some assembler code counting Delphi string references to Delphi Unicode

Tags: string, delphi

Dear Delphi Folks who know Assembler --

I have this great routine that worked fine in the pre-Unicode world.

```
function StringRefCount(const Src: String): Integer;
asm
  test eax, eax
  je   @Exit
  mov  edx, eax
  mov  eax, [edx - 8]

@Exit:
end;
```

Given that my ASM skills are rudimentary at best, how might this be done in D2009+ ?

ADDED: This test fails:

```
procedure TestStringStuff.TestStringRefCount;
var
  TempString: string;
  TempResult: Integer;
  SecondString: string;
begin
  TempString := 'this is a temp string';
  TempResult := StringRefCount(TempString);
  CheckEquals(1, TempResult);
  SecondString := TempString;
  TempResult := StringRefCount(TempString);
  CheckEquals(2, TempResult);
end;
```

Thanks -- I'm perfectly happy to admit to a major brain fart.  :-)

Nick

Comment: Your routine should work with Unicode strings. What is the problem?

Comment: I thought the same thing as Serg.  When Delphi changed the string layout, they prepended two fields to the data structure, but the rest remained intact, including the reference count at -8.

Comment: Hmm, well, it returns -1 for everything.  I'll look again.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you test with string constant - these always have refcout `-1`. Test with something like `TempString := Format('%f',[random()]);`.

Comment: It returns -1 because you access strings in readonly memory, works as designed.

Comment: Thank you all, you fine people.  Didn't realize that.

Comment: You really ought to convert that to Pascal. Then it will work on any platform.

Comment: `StringRefCount` is a standard function (in Delphi XE, not sure about prev versions), no need to reinvent it.

Comment: Even better, @Serg, and it's there in 2010 and I bet it was there even earlier.

Comment: I'm converting an older library forward -- didn't realize that System had the exact function.  I'm aliasing it now.  Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Nick:  Glad to hear that System has the routine you needed. But I'm sure I'm not the only one wondering why the need to know the reference count of a string?  Some byzantine memory optimization in a legacy app?  Please enlighten us!

Comment: I didn't know about StringRefCount, either.  Nice.  It appears to have been introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: Another point to make is that the code in the Q never worked in any version of Delphi. Literals have had ref count -1 for as long as I can remember. When you suspect a compiler difference causes behaviour that you can't explain, always run the different compiler versions on the same code. Here, you ran different code on different compiler versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No changes are necessary to that code for 32-bit compilers. It's the test case that's faulty because string literals have built-in reference counts of −1.

For 64-bit code (and 32-bit code on newer compilers), you're best off using the function by the same name already provided by the RTL.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see refcounting in action you must first create a string instance on the heap like this:

```
procedure TestStringStuff.TestStringRefCount;
var
  TempString: string;
  TempResult: Integer;
  SecondString: string;
begin
  TempString := 'this is a temp string';
  UniqueString(TempString);  // <-- !!
  TempResult := StringRefCount(TempString);
  CheckEquals(1, TempResult);
  SecondString := TempString;
  TempResult := StringRefCount(TempString);
  CheckEquals(2, TempResult);
end;
```

Comment: String constants also have a reference count field, for compatibility with all of the RTL functions that deal with strings.  The reference count of a constant is merely locked in at a value of -1, that's all.